# Деление длинных не целых чисел

Tags: алгоритм

Для интереса захотел попытаться реализовать класс, который выполняет арифметические операции, не влезающие в double и для интереса сделать не целую длинную арифметику.
Все бы хорошо, но вот с делением возникли проблемы.
Т.к если до этого можно было бы использовать стандартные алгоритмы для реализации длинной арифметики(сложение, вычитание, умножение) с учётом некоторой специфики в виду того, что работаем с не целыми числами, то по поводу деления, честно говоря, идей нет, тк приходят какие-то ужасные в плане производительности идеи.
Может кто-нибудь знает в какую сторону копать?
Был бы благодарен

Comment: Если нужно точное деление, то надо делать рациональные числа - пары взаимнопростых целых. Любая дробь в знаменателе которой не степень двойки не представима в виде целого числа умноженного на степень двойки (чем и является double, или любой его "старший брат"). Производительность тут не причем. Если деление точное.

Comment: Если деление приближённое, то можно заметить что обычное деление столбиком двоичных чисел почти неотличимо от двоичного поиска. Частное конструируется побитовото с проверкой что его произведение на делитель не превосходит делимое.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy ну, я использую массив для хранения чисел по основанию 1000 и, честно говоря, не представляю пока что, как предложенные решения на мою реализацию наложить, но попытаюсь разобраться. В любом случае спасибо!

Comment: В реальной жизни всегда используются числа с фиксированной точностью. Основное отличие таких чисел от аппаратных вещественных в том, что можно динамически менять точность вычислений. Например, в библиотеке GNU MP есть [множество функций для работы с точностью](https://gmplib.org/manual/Initializing-Floats). Поэтому внутри такие библиотеки используют те же алгоритмы, что и для деления больших целых. Для примера [алгоритмы деления в GMP](https://gmplib.org/manual/Division-Algorithms)